# Why does my linux server resolve all domains (even non-existant ones)

Tags: linux, domain-name-system, centos

Currently every domain name resolves to my primary server, `primary.example.com`. So for example, if I `ping randomdomain123.blah` I get:

```
PING primary.example.com` (1.2.3.4) 56(84) bytes of data.
```

but am expecting a 'host not found' error.

Initially I thought it was because I had `search example.com` in my `/etc/resolv.conf`. However, after removing that pinging `randomdomain123.blah` still resolves to my primary domain. Restarting the server had no effect either.

I have nothing specified in `/etc/hosts`.

Running `hostname` from another server in the cluster gives `secondary.example.com`.

I use Route 53 as the DNS provider, and relevant DNS seems to be:

```
example.com.            A       1.2.3.4
primary.example.com.    A       1.2.3.4
*.primary.example.com.  CNAME   primary.example.com
*.example.com.          CNAME   www.example.com
www.example.com.        CNAME   primary.example.com
```

So is this a local networking misconfiguration or some DNS problem? (or both?)

Update: The reason I want/need a wildcard is that I run a webapp of this domain so customer1.example.com etc. need to resolve to this machine and it needs to be automatic - so I wanted to avoid having to change the DNS after each new customer signs up.

Update 2: My `/etc/resolv.conf` is currently as follows (since I commented out the search line):

```
### Hetzner Online AG installimage
# nameserver config
nameserver 213.133.99.99
nameserver 213.133.100.100
nameserver 213.133.98.98
nameserver 2a01:4f8:0:a102::add:9999
nameserver 2a01:4f8:0:a0a1::add:1010
nameserver 2a01:4f8:0:a111::add:9898
# search example.com
```

Update 3: Running `dig randomdomain123.blah +trace` gives:

```
; <<>> DiG 9.8.2rc1-RedHat-9.8.2-0.30.rc1.el6 <<>> randomdomain123.blah +trace
;; global options: +cmd
;; Received 12 bytes from 213.133.99.99#53(213.133.99.99) in 0 ms
```

Update 4: I can confirm that `ping randomdomain123.blah.` with the final dot gives:

```
ping: unknown host randomdomain123.blah.
```

So does that mean that from a Java app on this machine, I need to append dots and use a URL like `http://randomdomain123.blah./somepage.html` to ever generate a HostNotFoundException?

Comment: Updated the question with better explanation.

Comment: Please don't munge domain names when you're asking about DNS issues, it makes it a lot harder to troubleshoot. And if you do munge them, don't just pick a random domain name that belongs to someone else - use **example.com** which is meant for this.

Comment: @JennyD Roger that.

Comment: Please add the contents of `/etc/resolv.conf` to your question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your problem is the `search` field in `/etc/resolv.conf` combined with your `*` record. You mentioned that you already tried to remove that setting. But it turns out that omitting it from `/etc/resolv.conf`, does not mean that the search feature will be turned off.

If absent from `/etc/resolv.conf` the `search` setting will default to the domain from your hostname.

I don't know if there is an official way to completely disable the `search` feature, but this appeared to work:

```
search .
```

Alternatively, you can point your `search` to a domain without a `*` record, which could contain a few other records for your convenience. For example:

```
search search.example.com
```

Then you can create records such as `server1.search.example.com` but not `*.search.example.com`.

Comment: Thanks! Adding the `search .` line did the trick!

Answer (score 3):

It looks like you have configured a wildcard DNS record, a so called catch it all configuration:
*.example.com is CNAMEs to www.example.com which in turn is a CNAME for primary.example.com which then resoves to 1.2.3.4

That is not a very sane setup, please also see: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wildcard_DNS_record.

Comment: Thanks - will check it out, plus added an explanation on why I have the wildcard.

Comment: But how can `randomdomain123.blah` ever map to *.example.com in the first place?

Comment: @Peter - I presume something is appending a 'default' extension making it treat it like `randomdomain123.blah.example.com`

Comment: @NicCottrell - please do a `dig randomdomain123.blah +trace`

Comment: dns domain suffix on the client. I think if you ping randomdomain123.blah. with the trailing dot then you will get the expected behavior

Comment: In regards to this being a sane setup: my logic was that I want all non-specified domains to go to our production webserver `www.`, but I want to be able to be able to update the pointer quickly should that server go down and I want to point it to our backup cluster. Is there a better way?